# Lefschetz (1,1) theorem for quasi-projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, hodge-theory

I was reading about Hodge conjecture on Wikipedia but it started with the assumption that $X$ is smooth projective.

If $X$ is a smooth quasi-projective variety, then corresponding to smooth sub-varieties of $X$ of codimension 1, one gets a class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Q})$. This cohomology also carries a Mixed Hodge structure. One should be able to phrase Hodge conjecture for such varieties.

My question is

1. Does it make sense to talk about Hodge conjecture for smooth(normal?) quasi-projective varieties? If yes, what would be the desired statement?
2. Can one prove it in the easiest of the cases? For example : lefschetz (1,1) theorem is the base case. If yes, proofs/references are most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: There are general versions of the Hodge conjectures by Beilinson. One needs to use Higher Chow groups. It seems, however, that the naive generalizations are false in complete generality. See Beilinson's Hodge conjecture for smooth varieties, Rob de Jeu and James D. Lewis.